# Reddit bot periodically opens reddit.com in commandline and stops running

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, raspbian, reddit

Before I begin, I'm using python3, praw, and [oauth2_util](https://github.com/SmBe19/praw-OAuth2Util) on the raspbian OS command line.

Every so often, a reddit bot that I've coded decides to stop doing what its supposed to do and instead opens reddit.com in the command line. It's got a white background when it does that, which confuses me because it looks almost exactly like elinks except it has a white background and this has a black background. Anyway, nowhere in my code is anything that would make it open reddit.com to my knowledge, which makes me even more confused.

The only time I've ever used linux is to host this reddit bot, so I have no idea how to copy the command line text to my main computer, so I just took a picture of the screen to get the error message.

Here is that: 
[image: Errors]

The keyboard interrupt is me stopping it after noticing that it has opened reddit.

Here is the full code of the reddit bot: https://github.com/Mjone77/Bitron

Is this a problem with OAuth2Util? If so I can just find a different reddit authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've [handled authentication at all](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/pages/oauth.html), so I'm guessing OAuth2Util is attempting to auth your script with reddit.